# What is an "Eumel"?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, colloquial

Sometimes in colloquial German I hear people saying:

> *"Hey, dieser **Eumel** hat schon wieder seine Tasche liegen lassen"*
>   *"He, Du **Eumel**, komm' halt mit."*

Obviously it is not really nice to say that to someone but also it seems not offensive either.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eumel) is not very helpful when it comes to explain what is meant by an *"Eumel"* as there are two opposing meanings listed:

> - (Jugendsprache veraltend) unsympathischer Mensch, Dummkopf
> - (Jugendsprache veraltend) umgänglicher, sympathischer Mensch

So now, is an *Eumel* someone who is nice or is it someone who is unlikeable? Where does this expression originate?

Comment: Du Eumel, warum weiß Du das nicht? ;)

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Den Begriff *Eumel* gibt es aber doch schon lange **vor** dem Werbespot aus den 70er Jahren, evtl. mit anderer Bedeutung?

Comment: Tut er, ja. Willst Du mich jetzt auf die Suche schicken, oder was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eumel was - according to [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumel) - a cartoon character in a 1970's advertisement of "Hoffmanns Gardinen-Neu", a curtain detergent that fought the "curtain varmints" (Eumels).

> Zeichentrickwerbefiguren („Gardinenschädlinge“) von Hoffmann’s Stärkefabriken aus den 1970er Jahren

To the question, if an "Eumel" is unlikeable: I think the word is not used in that way. You can call someone "Eumel" who does or says something stupid whithout losing your sympathy by that.

Comment: He acted stupidly in some way but you still like him. It was used mostly in the 1980s I think.

Comment: BTW, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumel

Comment: I personally know a couple (in their fifties) where one calls the other "Eumel" from time to time to tease him a little bit. He doesn't mind.

Comment: Agree with 0x6d64 and the last sentence in the answer. Eumel is used *liebevoll*.